# Make program instantly start up when login. c#

Tags: c#, authentication, startup

I have previously posted a question about this but I did not get an answer that suited my needs, so maybe I need to be more specific?

I am trying to make my program instantly start up when the person logs in. It is a computer locking device so I need it to start as soon as possible. I know this is possible because anti-virus programs do this. Such as [ESET](http://www.eset.co.uk/) or [Avira](http://www.avira.com/en/pages/index.php).

I currently have my program entering a key into the registry to enable it to start up when the user logs in. But I need it to be much more efficient to maximise security.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, most anti-virus programs run as a windows service.  If you need instant on then that's the only way to go.

The part you see starting after log in is simply the UI for those services.

Comment: Ah kk thanks, do you know of any guides to run it as a windows service?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx